# Applying title() to a column

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to print the second column of the csv file with the title() code. When I run this snippet it gives an error. Please provide assistance.

```
import csv

books = csv.reader(open('C:\\Users\\Data.csv','rb'))

for row in books:
    print [r.title(row[1]) for r in row]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\update.py", line 32, in <module>
    print [r.title(row[1]) for r in row]
TypeError: title() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass in an argument, and you can't have just `row[1]` title-cased by calling `title` on all columns.

Either use `str.title()` on just *one* column, or on all. To produce a list with only one element title-cased, you'd have to re-build the list with the one element replaced:

```
print row[:1] + [row[1].title()] + row[2:]
```

or edit the row in-place before printing:

```
row[1] = row[1].title()
print row[1]
```